# Сделать ячейку таблицы ссылкой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

Решил использовать [fancyBox3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) для вывода изображений. Но возникла проблема в том, что кнопки на моем сайте оформлены через `<td>` и `onclick`. А по этой библиотеке используется тег `<a>`, как можно обернуть ячейку так, чтобы она вся была ссылкой, при этом бы работал скрипт? Простое `<a><td></td></a>` не работает.

**UPD:** Судя по документации, это работает так:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Мне же нужно, чтобы работало так:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
        <td>Ячейка 1</td>
    </a>
```

При этом бы клик считался при нажатии любой части ячейки.

Comment: Добавьте [mcve]

Comment: А так нельзя делать и все :Р

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sth3p302/

Comment: @fanfer, моя Вам благодарность. Оформите ответ, чтобы я мог принять его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-fancybox href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Ячейка-ссылка</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```